# create modelless dialog angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dialog, modal-dialog

I am searching for a AngularJS dialog which is not modal and should have options minimize, maximize, close. My requirement is to open one dialog from parent and can be able to do other things in main page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want something bare minimal try something like [ngDialog](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/)

Basic usage is along these lines:

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'popupTmpl.html', className: 'ngdialog-theme-default' });
    };
});
```

So as you will see you can programatically open a dialog with `ngDialog.open({ template: 'popupTmpl.html', className: 'ngdialog-theme-default' });`

Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)

Comment: seems to be this creates modal dialog not the modal less . i am looking for  dialog which is not modal